# How can I solve the second order PDE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

How can I solve the second order PDE?

$x^2u_{xx}+2xyu_{xy}+y^2u_{yy}+xyu_x+y^2u_y=0$.

*Solution:*

I find $\Delta=0$.Then, $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y}{x}$ and from here I find $\frac{x}{y}=c_1$

Now, will I define $\xi(x,y)=\frac{x}{y}$ and $\eta=y$ ? Can you help me?

Comment: Maple says: $u \left( x,y \right) =-{\frac {1}{y} \left( {\it F1} \left( {\frac {y
}{x}} \right) x{{\rm e}^{-y}}-{\it F2} \left( {\frac {y}{x}} \right) y
 \right) }
$ where F1 and F2 arbitrary function

Comment: Could you share the Maple code?

Comment: Maple code:
`PDE := x^2*(diff(u(x, y), x$2))+2*x*y*(diff(u(x, y), x, y))+y^2*(diff(u(x, y), y$2))+x*y*(diff(u(x, y), x))+y^2*(diff(u(x, y), y)) = 0:pdsolve(PDE);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, nothing prevents you from taking $\eta = y$ in this parabolic equation. You must make sure that the transformation $(x,y) \to (\xi,\eta)$ is not 'degenerate' or 'singular' (sorry if I'm not wording this accurately), like, for instance, $\eta = 1$ (you would be mapping variables into a constant!).

But it's good practice to convince yourself that this is indeed a good choice for $\eta$. Indeed, if you let $\eta = f(x,y)$ for some general $f$ and work out the partial derivatives in terms of $\xi$ and $\eta$ you'll find:

$$ (x f_x + y f_y)^2 \, u_{\eta \eta} + (x^2 f_{xx} + y^2 f_{yy} + xy f_x + y^2 f_y) \, u_\eta = 0 $$

If, as you suggest, one takes the good choice $\eta = y$, the following 'ODE' for $u$ is found:

$$ u_{\eta \eta} + u_\eta = 0$$

Solving by means of any of your favourite methods, you have

$$u(\xi,\eta)  = A(\xi) + B(\xi) \mathrm{e}^{-\eta}$$

where $A$ and $B$ are arbitrary functions of their arguments. As you can see, everything turned out well and easy. I leave it to you to think what would happen for another choice of $\eta$.

Moreover, what happens for $y=0$? And for $x = 0$? And for $x=y$?

Comment: For $y=0$, I found $-xu_{\xi\eta}=0$

Comment: I solved again w.r.t. your  equation in upwards and I found $y^2u_{\eta\eta}+y^2u_{\eta}=0$. Then, we have again $u_{\eta\eta}+u_{\eta}=0$ ?

Comment: Substituting $\xi$ and $\eta$, we get $u(x/y,y)=A(x/y)+B(x/y)e^{-y}$.  But, if $u(x/y,y)=A(x/y)+B(x/y)e^{-y}$, how can we reach $u(x,y)$?

Comment: @HD239, you can put it the way you prefer, saying $u(x,y) = A(x/y) + B(x/y) e^{-y}$ is correct. Just watch out if you have to take derivatives!